# jQuery validate plugin - how to turn off non-submit validation results?

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, jquery-validate

I use jquery validation plugin in hand with form plugin for jQuery.

I turned on validation of email format, it is ok that it started to validate emails on the run and tells user immediately that he/she typed invalid email format.

**However** it is not OK that this check also fires up the error message box - is there a way to force validation() to show error labels next to inputs but at the same time to not to fire/show error_box? (in result) . I want to add anything to the result box AFTER user clicks the submit button - is it possible ?

**EDIT:** I thought it was clear, clearly it is not so I am adding the piece of code :)

**EDIT 3:** Where I am heading to: I DO want the messages in the *target: .result* but ONLY after clicking submit button - NOT anytime sooner it should be more clear now :)

```
      var zadost = $("#validate_zadost").validate({
          focusInvalid: false,
          submitHandler: function(form) {
                  $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                          target: ".result",
                          success: function(){ zadost.resetForm(); }
                  });
          },
          showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            $(".result")
              .html("<div class='error_box'><h1>Nebyly vyplňeny povinné údaje nebo byly vyplňeny špatně!</h1><p>Žádost nebyla odeslána - prosím doplňte povinné údaje (ve správném formátu). (červeně zvýrazněny)</p></div>");
            this.defaultShowErrors();
          },
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) { //error message and JQUERY element coming...
            if( element.is(':checkbox') ) error.insertBefore(element).addClass('zadostErrorCheckbox');
              else error.insertAfter(element);
          }

  });
```

Comment: Added additional explanation to make answer more clear :)

Answer (score 2):

[See the documentation.](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

**Quote Title:**

> *"how to turn off non-submit validation results?"*

Sounds like you want to turn off all the "events"...

```
$('#myform').validate({
    // options & rules,
    onkeyup: false,    // prevent validation on every key up
    onfocusout: false, // prevent validation after leaving field
    onclick: false     // prevent validation when clicking radio and checkbox
});
```

Do not use the `onsubmit` option since it's already the default behavior (setting it to `true` will break the plugin).

**Quote OP:**

> *"However it is not OK that this check also fires up the error message box - is there a way to force `validate()` to show error labels next to inputs but at the same time to not to fire/show `error_box`? (in result). I want to add anything to the result box AFTER user clicks the submit button - is it possible?"*

I can't see your code so I don't know what you've done, however, showing only error message labels next to the input fields ***is*** already the *default* behavior.  Something in your code must be causing the other things to happen here.

**edit:** remove your entire `showErrors` callback function if you don't want to show the error box and only show errors in labels next to input elements.

Comment: edit: - that is not where I am heading to I DO want the messages in the target: .result but ONLY after clicking submit button - NOT anytime sooner - do you understand what exactly do I want to achive now ? :)

Comment: @jave.web, ok, I understand now but AFAIK it's not possible to defer the same message in place and not another.

Comment: OK well then showErrors removing could be the way - is there some way to add your own action to validation process ? (without touching the plugin) ?

Comment: @jave.web, _"your own action"_?  I don't know what that means.  You can write custom callback functions for any of the available options.  If that's not enough, then you'll need to write your own or modify this plugin.

Comment: I was looking for a way how to pass an action (function that will be executed) to some already existing callback, unfortunately it seems there is no way like that. And since I dont want to touch the plugin because of possible plugin updates, I will go just for the showError turn off and will turn on focusing again ... thanks for help anyway